# Python: Remove items in list of list by index

Tags: python, list

Here i want remove items in list of list by index.
Input is

```
li  = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

Excepted output is

```
[[1,3,4],[5,7,8]]
```

What I'm tried is,

```
print [x.pop(1) for x in li]
```

Comment: After `[x.pop(1) for x in li]` `li` will have your desired output. You just need to print it `print li`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `del` operator like this:

```
for sublist in list:
    del sublist[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually removed the items in the given index but you printed out the wrong list. Just print `li` after you pop the items:

```
>>> [x.pop(1) for x in li]
>>> print li
```

However, do you really have to use list comprehensions? Because calling  `.pop()` in a list comprehension will accumulate the removed items and creates a new, totally useless list with them.

Instead, you can just do the following:

```
>>> for lst in li:
...    lst.pop(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pop`, like `del` change the underlying list so you must explicitely loop through the sublists to remove second element and them print the modified list.

```
for l in li: del l[1]
print li
```

If on the other hand, you do not want to change the lists but directly print the result, you could use a list comprehension:

```
print [ (l[:1] + l[2:]) for l in li ]
```